# Windows Server Task Scheduler -> trigger on an event(triggered by stored procedure)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, taskscheduler

could i schedule a task triggered by an event, and this event would be stored procedure..so I want to trigger it after successfully executing of a stored procedure. Can this be done and how? Many Thanks

Comment: How do you execute your stored procedure?

Comment: through a sql job...it is not yet done..it is in project phase, another idea I have is to make an ssis package and to include in a sql job